# How to use a template with ActiveForm->checkboxList

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I'm looking to use a template for my checkboxList. I'm using templates on other ActiveForm fields but it doesn't seem to work on checkboxList field.

I just need to get the input set to col-sm-7 instead of 6.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'days', [
            'template' => "<div class='col-sm-3'>{label}</div><div class='col-sm-7'>\n{input}</div>\n{hint}\n{error}"])
             ->inline()
             ->checkboxList(Onlinestore::$days, []) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option `checkboxTemplate` in `ActiveField`. It should be [template](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$template-detail):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'days', ['template' => "<div class='col-sm-3'>{label}</div><div class='col-sm-7'>\n{input}</div>\n{hint}\n{error}"])
    ->inline()
    ->checkboxList(Onlinestore::$days, []) ?>
```

Comment: My bad, that was something I tried. Since it is a property for ActiveField. I'm afraid it doesn't solve the problem though. Thanks anyway.